# There exists a scalar $k$ such that $T^{2018}$ = $k^{2017}T$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, induction

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ with dimension of $V$ being $d \geq2$. Given that $\text{rank}(T) = 1 $, prove that there exists a scalar $k$ sucht that $T^{2018}$ = $k^{2017}T$.

---

This was a problem on an exam I had yesterday and there is already a solution posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3629856/641078), but I'm curious if my reasoning is the same as the solution Kavi Rama provides.

I also said that given that $T$ is unidimensional it sends most vectors in $V$ to zero and that would be the trivial case where $k = 0$. Otherwise, for the only vector that forms a basis of $R(T)$, it is automatically the eigenvector of $T$ and thus set $k$ to be the corresponding $\lambda$.

Should I be using induction instead as the guys over [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3629856/641078) do?
Thank you!

Comment: I'd go your way and say that $T$ is an automorphism of $TV$; this space being one-dimensional, it is just a scalar $k$ there. So on $TV$,we have  $T^{2017}=k^{2017}$;  and on $V$, we have $T^{2018}=k^{2017}T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the range of $c=k^{2017}$ where $c \in \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$ itself, the question can be reduced to 
$$T^{2018}x=cx$$ where $c$ is some scalar.

Since $rank(T)=1$, it must knock the whole $V$ into a single line. 
That is, given any vector $x$, $Tx$ will be located inside the one dimensional column space of $T$. Thus $Tx$ and $T^{2018}x$ must be on the same line. That is,
$$T^{2018}x=cx$$ where c is some scalar.

If it is required to present the answer in the form $k^{2017}x$, then we can just extend upon this argument a little.
$Tx$ must be an eigenvector of $T$ since $T^2x$ must exist on the same line. If we take the eigenvalue to be $k$, then $T^2x$=$kTx$.
It follows that,
$$T^{2018}x=k^{2017}Tx$$
and removing x from both sides,
$$T^{2018}=k^{2017}T$$
for some scalar $k$